# Limits of a function $f(x)=(x+3)\dfrac{|x+2|}{x+2}$

Tags: limits

Given $f(x)=(x+3)\dfrac{|x+2|}{x+2}$, how do you find the 
            $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -2^{+}}f(x)$$
Obviously it is one but am looking for a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\gt -2$ then $|x+2|=x+2$. So we want $\lim_{x\to -2^+} (x+3)$.

**Remark:** If something is obvious, a clear description of why it is obvious usually turns quickly into a proof.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is taken from above, so the term $|x+2|/(x+2) \rightarrow +1$ in the limit.  Therefore the limit value is $(-2+3)(+1) = 1$.

In general, the ratio of $|f(x)|/f(x)$ is equal to the sign of $f(x)$ away from places $x_0$ where $f(x)=0$.  When taking the limit as $x \rightarrow x_0$, we must consider whether the limit is from above or below in order to get the sign right.

Comment: I thought so since both $|x+2|$ and $(x+2)$ have the same value for values to the right of $-2$, but very close.